# Database query with Ruby/SQLite implementation

Tags: ruby, sqlite

I have a web page whereby users select 'create new request', this takes them to a page where they are presented with a reference number, and they complete/submit the form. The data they submit is then stored in a SQLite database.

I feel like I'm working backwards by having the application access the SQL and get the reference number first prior to the User submitting the form. I would really like some pointers or reference material they may help.

Comment: It is difficult to tell what the problem is from this description. Perhaps add the one or two relevant lines from your controller and/or form. Also, what is it about this application that requires the existence of the reference before the creation of the request, and are there any constraints on the value of the reference (that may require the database - e.g. does it have to be from a strict sequence)?

Comment: ok good point. The reference number could come after the submission of the form. Probably easier to control and define. The reason for the reference number to appear first was to match an existing fault ticketing system that is in place.